# match two number files to get out of range and within range

Tags: unix, awk, numbers, range, match

Executing  :

```
awk -v FILE1="FILE1.out" -v FILE2="FILE2.out" '
     FNR==NR {BLs[++BSize]=$1;BHs[BSize]=$2;next}  {Blacked=0   for( i=1; i<BSize && ! Blacked; i++) Blacked = ( $2 >= BLs[i] && $2 <= BHs[i])
     if ( Blacked ) print > FILE2
      else print > FILE1
     }' BlackList_B_Number.dat 2OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111
```

With these Input files:

```
cat BlackList_B_Number.dat 

902123123    902123124 
902123127    902123128 
 015                017 
450                600

cat 2OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111 

111111111 902123124    201605 
111111111 902123125    201605
 111111111 902123126   201605 
111111111 902123126    201605 
111111111 902123123    201605 
111111111 902123123    201605 
111111111 016    201605240 
111111111 1     20160524011
111111111 3    20160524024 
111111111 423   201605240 
111111111 5    20160524053 
111111111 470   201605240 
111111111 600   201605240 
111111111 400   424242432
```

FILE2 should have the 470 and 600, but is not there, It´s printed on FILE1.

```
cat FILE2.out 
111111111    902123124    201605
111111111    902123123    201605 
111111111    902123123    201605 
111111111    016     201605240
```

Answer (score 0):

a slight rewrite with the expected result

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {low[NR]=$1;hi[NR]=$2;n=NR;next} 
               {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                  if($2>=low[i] && $2<=hi[i]) 
                    {print > "inrange"; next}
                print > "not_inrange"}' data calls



==> inrange <==
111111111 902123124    201605 
111111111 902123123    201605 
111111111 902123123    201605 
111111111 016    201605240 
111111111 470   201605240 
111111111 600   201605240 

==> not_inrange <==
111111111 902123125    201605
111111111 902123126   201605 
111111111 902123126    201605 
111111111 1     20160524011
111111111 3    20160524024 
111111111 423   201605240 
111111111 5    20160524053 
111111111 400   424242432
```